# How to use a backslash in css content property?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a backslash after every list item, but I can't get it to work. It works if I use a pipe or a forward slash, but not a backslash. I searched for a character entity code to use, but I can't find one for a backslash. Is there a solution?

```
#navigation ul.nav > li:after{
    content: " \ ";
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use double backslash

```
#navigation ul.nav > li:after{
    content: '\\';
}
```

To know more about CSS escape sequences check [this](http://www.merttol.com/articles/code/introduction-to-css-escape-sequences.html)

use double backslash

```css
    span:after{
        content: '\\';
    }
```

```html
<span></span>
```

**`\005C`**

Use `\005C` in content as @disinfor mentioned

```css
    span:after{
        content: '\005C';
    }
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Will mark correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Or you can use this: `\005C`

Comment: @disinfor ya true. thanks, I have updated that. thanks for mentioning

Comment: Here's an [Entity Conversion Calculator](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) you can use to find the values for other characters

Comment: Nice info @tomaroo

Comment: Oh cool. I'll use the entity code. And that calculator will be helpful  @tomaroo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hey i want spend a full example

```
    $dsp-md-imprint: "e900";

    @function unicode($str){
      @return unquote("\"")+unquote(str-insert($str, "\\", 1))+unquote("\"")
    }

    @mixin makeIcon($arg, $val , $os: null) {
      // @debug $os;
      // @debug $arg;
      // @debug $val;
      @if($os) {
        .ion-#{$arg}:before,
        .ion-#{$os}-#{$arg}:before ,
        .ion-#{$os}-#{$arg}-outline:before {
          content: unicode($val);
        }
      } @else {
        .ion-#{$arg}:before,
        .ion-#{$arg}-outline:before,
        .ion-md-#{$arg}:before,
        .ion-md-#{$arg}-outline:before,
        .ion-ios-#{$arg}:before,
        .ion-ios-#{$arg}-outline:before {
          content: unicode($val);
        }
      }

}

@include makeIcon(dsp-imprint, $dsp-md-imprint, md);
```

and can be tested [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/15848d2f99bd10ca3449dbbaa9d2bbcd)